# Consul share network from docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, consul, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-consul

There is consul server in docker.

```
  vote-consul-server:
    image: consul:1.7.2
    environment:
      CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE: eth0
    ports:
      - "${CONSUL_PORT}:8500"
```

It generates hosts for registred applications. 
The main problem is that anothers applications can't communicate between each other if they are not in docker.

For example: I have config-service (docker with consul), user-service(IDE). 
When user-service starts, it asks for configurations from config-server, but consul gives not correct link (available only in docker network).

```
c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://83a6c7ab12d0:8888/
```

How to publish all links from consul(docker)?

Answer (score 1):

Since every container has own `IP` and may have own network, you can try to use `host` networking:

```
docker run --rm -d --network host --name vote-consul-server
```

For more details, see [host networking tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/).

Also, you can learn about [networking from the container’s point of view](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all - need to define IP address configuration in bootstrap.yaml

```
spring:
  ...
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: ${CONSUL_HOST}
      port: ${CONSUL_PORT}
      discovery:
        ip-address: ${CONSUL_HOST}
        prefer-ip-address: true
```

The main properties are: ip-address and prefer-ip-address.

If all aplications work in one network - problem doesn't exist.
For example: all services work in docker.